# When A/B testing is not possible

Tags: propensity-scores

I need some methodological advice :

I have a population which at a certain time received a treatment (I use clinical terms for practical reasons).

I have then been asked what was the effect of the treatment on my population.

We are not in the case of **A/B testing** as treatment / non treatment populations are the same and there is no random assignment. Moreover, there is a time effect on the population ( the population evolves in time  ) : even with no treatment some changes are observed.

I thought maybe I could use **propensity score** matching, pairing individuals from the population as it was, with individuals from the population as it is...

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It sounds like you need to talk to a statistical consultant. The analysis of observational data is a complex field and requires extensive knowledge and training to do correctly. A lot of science is plagued by the fact that most people do it poorly. Any advice you get on this forum will not be sufficient for you to perform the analysis yourself. People spend years getting PhDs to be qualified to do this. I am sorry to gatekeep and I do think it is possible to teach yourself, but don't think any answer you get here will substitute for specific training or the expertise of a professional.

Comment: Hi Noah, in that particular case it is an experiment not an observational study : the treatment is imposed on individuals to measure their responses. We try to influence the response ( by the treatment ) which is not the case for an observational study. Anyway, I will carefully proceed so that what I hope to obtain shall be as accurate as possible. Controls will be put in place to verify the veracity of the choices made on the basis of the study conducted.

Comment: It's an observational study when the treatment is not randomly assigned. It sounds like you might have a randomized trial with noncompliance (i.e., not all participants obey the treatment they were given). But this is yet another added complication that requires the help of an expert.